# Is there a way to cache only GET Ajax request?

Tags: nginx, ajax

Usually I have in nginx config rules which does not allow cache all XMLHttpRequest:

```
map $http_x_requested_with $nocache_01 {
    default         0;
    XMLHttpRequest  1;
}
```

Is there a way to cache only GET Ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the $request_method

It's unshown, but assumed there's an if block in the config like so:

```
if ($nocache_01) {
    ...
}
```

Instead, by concatenating this variable with the request method, a more explicit check is possible i.e.:

```
if ($nocache_01$request_method = "1GET") {
    ...
}
```

Or, e.g., without using a map at all:

```
if ($http_x_requested_with$request_method = "XMLHttpRequestGET") {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank for [AD7six](http://serverfault.com/users/108287/ad7six) for prompting. Now, my maps looks as it. `map $http_x_requested_with $nocache_01 { default 0; XMLHttpRequestGET 0; XMLHttpRequestPUT 1; XMLHttpRequestPATCH 1; XMLHttpRequestDELETE 1; XMLHttpRequestPOST 1; }
`

Comment: Your comment is missing `$request_method` - But I wondered if you'd choose do that =). Note that a map [can be a regex](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) so e.g. `~XMLHttpRequest 1;` takes care of all the other XHR permutations.

Comment: AD7six, thank you again :) Do you mean something like this?

`map $http_x_requested_with$request_method $nocache_01 {
        default                                0;
        XMLHttpRequestGET                      0;
        ~XMLHttpRequest(PUT|PATH|DELETE|POST)  1;
}
`

I use this variable here 
`fastcgi_no_cache $nocache_01;
fastcgi_cache_bypass $nocache_01;`

Comment: @RostyslavMalenko yes. Though you don't need `(PUT|PATH|DELETE|POST)` if by that you really mean "all other http methods". It's appropriate btw to write an answer to your own question - if it differs from other existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Thank for [AD7six](https://serverfault.com/users/108287/ad7six) for prompting. Now, my maps looks as it.

`map $http_x_requested_with$request_method $nocache_01 {
        default                                0;
        XMLHttpRequestGET                      0;
        ~XMLHttpRequest(PUT|PATH|DELETE|POST)  1;
}`

This is mean that XMLHttpRequest(PUT|PATH|DELETE|POST) will not be cached

`fastcgi_no_cache $nocache_01;
fastcgi_cache_bypass $nocache_01;`